# "Hard Reload" shows different results than fresh visit (from new device), any idea why?

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache, cloudflare, multisite

having some cache issues(I think), but can't figure out where the problem is.

When I do a Hard Reload I get the new results but after clearing all my browsers cache (Chrome) it still loads the old version of the site while visiting normally.

I thought it was just the browser's cache but then I tried fresh devices that never had visited the site and I'm getting the same issue, the old site version.

-I've talked with my host (Host Gator Resseller) and they say they dont have any server level cache.

-I'm not running any cache plugins on my site (WPMU Install, X theme)

-I did have cloudflare installed but have since disabled it, purged the cache, and turned on developer mode and nothing.

-Tried new devices from multiple locations and connections and the problem persist, so it can't be browser related nor ISP related.

-Also tried incognito, and nothing.

I seriously can't think of where the problem is, any idea?

Comment: What is a hard reload?

Comment: Probably an ISP caching problems.

Comment: Don't think is the ISP since I tried from different connections/devices across different cities.